# 1 John 4, John 3; Could we conclude that the believers are of two kinds?

Tags: john, jesus, 1-john

1 John 4:10; KJV;

> 10 Herein is love, **not that we loved God, but that he loved us**, and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our sins.

1 John 4:4-5; KJV;

> 4 **Ye are of God**, little children, and have overcome them: because greater is he that is in you, than he that is in the world.
> 5 **They are of the world**: therefore speak they of the world, and the world heareth them.

John 3:16; KJV;

> 16 For **God so loved the world**, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.
> 17 For God sent **not** his Son into the world **to condemn the world;** but that the world through him might be saved.
> 18 He that believeth on him is not condemned: but he that believeth not is condemned already, because he hath not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God.

Could we conclude that the *Believers*, and hence the *Sinners*, are of two kinds:

- from God.
- from the world?

Comment: Really, sinners from God?

Comment: @steveowen the sinner who repent is, surely, from God. I think. The ability to sin is the consequence of free will. We are not robots.

Comment: @steveowen Also, Sins are of two kinds according to scriptures, 1. Sins not to death, 2. Sins not to death. This according to scriptures.

Comment: Without God’s provision of truth, there is only the illusion of free will. No one has true free will if they are deceived. Repentance is *only* from God. We don’t need an ability to sin, it is the default nature of corrupted mankind, it is not chosen, it is what we do. Any desire to do good originates from God, even unknowingly.

Comment: @steveowen Has a free will=Has the ability to sin.

Comment: @steveowen I think you understood my question well in your answer. You spoke about Sinners and Believers.

Comment: @steveowen By Adam's Sin, the Sin entered to the world, not the world became a Sinner, and deserve Punishment. The Original Sin Doctrine needs review.

Comment: @steveowen Sins of two kinds: 1. Sins not to death. 2. Sins to death.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basic facts:

1. ALL people are sinners - see Rom 3:10-18.  Therefore, ALL have sinned, Rom 3:23, 24
2. God came to save ALL people from the same world of sin, John 3:16, 12:32, 1 John 2:2, 2 Cor 5:18, 19, 1 Tim 2:3, 4, etc.
3. All sinners love the world, 1 John 2:15, 1 Tim 1:15, John 15:19, Rom 12:1, etc.  There is only one type of sinner - the person who loves the world and thus, not Jesus.
4. Salvation is the initiative of God alone, never us.  Phil 2:13, John 6:44, Rom 2:4, Acts 5:31, 11:18, 2 Tim 2:25
5. Our response to God is to return His love because, we are told, "We love because He first loved us", 1 John 4:19.
6. The whole purpose of salvation is to restore the image of God in us that was marred by sin.  This is the miraculous work of God via the Holy Spirit, Rom 12:1-3, 1 John 2:6, 1 Cor 2:16, 3:18, Col 3:1-3, etc.

Not all will accept the gracious offer of Jesus of eternal life, but of those who have and will do, ALL are in this sense alike - all will be converted from a life of sin to a life of loving service to God.

It is this change process that the OP's texts refer to when people go from being children of the world to children of God.

Comment: you didn't clearly answer my question, are believers  of two kinds, according to scriptures?

Comment: @salah - see the final paragraph - there is only one type of saved sinner

Comment: are Sinners of two kinds; of God, and of the World?!

Comment: @salah - by definition, a sinner is NOT of God.  There are only worldly sinners.

Comment: could you include this item in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

No, all are of the world. Only Jesus is ‘heavenly' being without sin.

> If you were of the world, it would love you as its own. Instead, the world hates you, because you are not of the world, but I have chosen you **out of the world**. John 15:19

> And He was saying to them, “You are from below, I am from above; you are of this world, I am not of this world John 8:23

Believers become *not* of the world when God takes us into His realm through Christ.

> He has rescued us **from the dominion of darkness** and brought us into the kingdom of His beloved Son Col 1:13

Then, we become “from God”, having overcome as Jesus did. Not that we *have* already overcome, but we became overcomers
in Christ.